# QVector Out of memory

Tags: qt

При попытке загрузить в вектор непомерный объем данных с помощью append() программа крэшится и в консоль выдается:

`In file ..\..\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qvector.h, line 544: Out of memory`

Никаких исключений при этом не выбрасывается. Судя по исходникам в этом случае вызывается qFatal() и программа завершается. Получается, нет никаких способов перехватить ошибку об нехватке памяти ?

OS:win7
Qt ver: 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может это не совсем хороший способ перехвата, но можно перехватить qFatal с помощью qInstallMessageHandler. С примером использования можно ознакомиться в оффициальной документации : [doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler)

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста минимальный пример

Comment: Так в доке же хороший пример: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler

Comment: @PavelGridin пройдёт пара лет, в доке поменяют оглавление и ссылка станет вести на 404. Очень часто такое бывает.

Comment: Ну и у нас тут просто принято, что в ответе должно быть достаточно информации для решения, а не просто ссылка куда-нибудь ещё. :)